# Django uploaded images not displayed

Tags: django, image-uploading

I have problem displaying images uploaded through form. Here are the relevant parts:

models.py

```
def get_uplaod_file_name(instance,filename): #rename the uploaded file
    return 'uploaded_files/%s_%s' % (str(time()).replace('.','_'), filenam

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    thumbnail = models.FileField(upload_to=get_uplaod_file_name)
```

fomrs.py

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model= UserProfile
        fields = ( 'name', 'occupation', 'city', 'thumbnail')
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def user_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, 
                               instance=request.user.profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            message = 'Your profile is updated!'
            return render_to_response('home.html',{'message':message}, 
                                      context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

In the template, instead of the full image path I just get:

```
<img src="/static/assets/uploaded_files/" width="200" />
```

While the image file is properly uploaded to the static folder. So I really got confused and appreciate your hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your template contain the following?

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

Do you have the static folder defined in your settings.py?

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    'filepath/to/folder'
)
```

Try loading pictures like this

```
<img src="{% static "/static/assets/uploaded_files/" %}" width="200" />
```

Comment: Actually the problem was a silly mistake in defining thumbnail template. I modified it to <img src="/static/assets/{{profile.thumbnail}}" width="200" /> and now it displays. Appreciate your hint Cody.